# How to delete duplicate rows in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help with duplicate rows. I have deleted the duplicate rows from one table using the following method

```
DELETE FROM names a
WHERE ROWID > (SELECT MIN(ROWID) FROM names b
WHERE b.name=a.name
AND b.age=a.age
);
```

It did work with that particular table but I did the same thing with another table which has duplicate reference numbers for each doctor but different unique codes.

```
doc_name  ref_no  unique_code
------------------------------
abcd      1010     1111
abcd      1010     1112
cdef      1011     1113
cdef      1011     1114
```

My result should look like this:

```
doc_name ref_no unique_code
---------------------------
abcd     1010      1111
cdef     1011      1113
```

Comment: what is the query you used for the 2nd query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try it like this ?

```
DELETE FROM names a
WHERE ROWID > (SELECT MIN(ROWID) FROM names b
WHERE b.doc_name=a.doc_name
AND b.ref_no=a.ref_no
)
```

try this also

```
SELECT *
  FROM doc_unique
 WHERE (DIV_CD, DOC_NAME, B_DT, FT_NM, UNQ_CD, DESG_CD,
 SPEC_CD) IN (SELECT DIV_CD, DOC_NAME, B_DT, FT_NM, UNQ_CD, DESG_CD,
 SPEC_CD
                             FROM doc_unique
                            GROUP BY DIV_CD, DOC_NAME, B_DT, FT_NM, UNQ_CD, DESG_CD,
 SPEC_CD HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Comment: Moudiz,i did a manual search on the table and also checked for duplicate values but there was none could be found. can you tell me if this is the proper way to check for duplicate rows


`select DIV_CD,DOC_NAME,B_DT,FT_NM,UNQ_CD,
DESG_CD,SPEC_CD,count(*) from doc_unique 
group by DIV_CD,DOC_NAME,B_DT,FT_NM,
UNQ_CD,DESG_CD,SPEC_CD 
having count(unq_cd)>1`

Comment: @Iftekhar yes it seems good however check this query , its another way to check duplicate

Comment: your query to check for duplicates worked.thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

You can use [ROW_NUMBER()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm), to detect duplicate rows and delete them.

```
DELETE tblName
WHERE ROWID IN (
    SELECT ROWID
    FROM(
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY doc_name, ref_no ORDER BY doc_name, ref_no) AS Rn
            ,doc_name
            ,ref_no
            ,unique_code
      FROM tblName
    )
    WHERE Rn > 1
   )
```

Comment: You can't delete from a CTE in Oracle

Comment: @sqluser i tried your query.it showed me the following error: 

     `WITH C AS(  
    
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY doc_name, ref_no     ORDER BY doc_name, ref_no) AS Rn ,  doc_name ,  ref_no     ,  unq_cd FROM doc_unique )   DELETE FROM C WHERE Rn > 1`   SQL> / DELETE FROM C WHERE Rn > 1   * ERROR at line 8: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword

Comment: @Iftekhar, as @a_horse_with_no_name mentioned in his comment we cannot delete from a `CTE`. So I changed the query. Please see the updated. Thanks to @a_horse_with_no_name for pointing it out.

Comment: @sqluser,thanks for the updated query.i have changed the new query a little as there is no ref_no in the table where i am looking to delete the duplicate rows.will the new query work or should i include father's name(ft_nm) and mother's name(mt_nm) too?

`DELETE t_doc_unique
WHERE ROWID IN (
    SELECT ROWID
    FROM(
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY doc_name,unq_cd ORDER BY doc_name, unq_cd) AS Rn
            ,doc_name
            ,unq_cd
      FROM t_doc_unique
    )
    WHERE Rn > 1
   )
/`

Answer (score 1):

Please, try `exists`

```
delete from names a
where exists (
  select * 
  from names b
  where b.name = a.name
        and b.age = a.age
        and a.unique_code > b.unique_code 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can delete duplicate data by using following sql query:**

delete from [table_name]
where rowid in
(
select max(rowid) from [table_name] group by [column_name]
);

**Note:** [table_name] like STUDENT and [column_name] like STUD_ID

[Find Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxFJT.png)

Comment: Avoid sharing screenshots, link might get broken throughout time

Comment: Thank you for sharing, I will take care from now @atish.s